# How to take backup of all installed APKs from Phone to PC?

Tags: backup, adb, apk, command-line

How do I take backup of all installed apks from my sgs2 to PC using android sdk/ 3rd party tool etc? My phone is not rooted. I can install/uninstall apks using adb, but is there any similar command line tool to take backup of the same?

Comment: If you're not rooted then I think the answer is pretty much that you can't, but perhaps someone more familiar with Samsung can say for certain (don't know if Kies offers any kind of backup ability).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the things that are far easier with a rooted phone: you could just type in:

```
adb pull /data/app C:\Users\User\Desktop\Apps
```

and your apks would magically appear on your desktop. In your case this isn't possible because accessing the data partition is only allowed for root users. (And this is a good thing. Imagine what would happen if any app could read your email or text messages.)

There are several apps in the <del>android market</del> play store that can back up your apps.
My favorite is [App Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup&feature=search_result). It's a pretty simple app that even has an option to automatically back up all new apps.
Than you can just copy  the apps to your computer using your preferred method. I use [Foldersync Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite&feature=search_result) to upload it to my DropBox.

Comment: There are desktop apps which can backup the apks without the root on phone (http://www.wondershare.com/android-manager/). But I want to know how.. any idea?

Comment: being rooted doesn't mean that "any app could read your email"

Comment: I never said it means that. Just that if /data would be readable by any app like /mnt/sdcard than any app could read it.