# how to acces to apk using backup?

Tags: backup, adb, restore

I want to use adb backup restore, but I'd like to know if possible to know the contents back up file if yes so how. is it possible to have access only to apk. to install on other devices. i don't want to use adb backup -apk.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20606/how-to-take-backup-of-all-installed-apks-from-phone-to-pc

Comment: or maybe http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28481/how-do-you-extract-an-apps-data-from-a-full-backup-made-through-adb-backup depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Dan is correct with his comment on the question, see especially [my answer there](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/42224/16575) on how to convert an `.ab` file to a `.tar` and then access the contents.

`.apk` files (if backed up, of course) are stored in `apps/com.app.name/a/` then. But if `adb backup` was used without `-apk`: no `.apk` files then (your question is a bit confusing: "I want to use it...I don't want to use it" :)

If your goal is just to get hold of the `.apk` files of installed apps, you might also want to take a look at solutions like e.g. [AppMonster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager), which allow you to get a copy of each installed app's `.apk` file to your SDCard (with the Pro-Version even in Batch Mode, and automatically on each app install). You could then use e.g. `adb pull` to copy the entire backup directory to your PC, and `adb push` to restore it to other devices for installation with e.g. `adb shell pm install`.